# Change the label of a cell

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

[image]
Hello, I have a block like the following, I want to change the label as follows (to the blue color). Could you please help me with that?Thank you

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta,decorations, positioning, arrows.meta, calc, shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{block/.style={draw, fill=blue!15, rectangle, minimum height=1.7em, minimum width=2em},
cell/.style={rectangle, rounded corners=5mm, fill=green!15, draw,very thick,}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
\node [cell, minimum height =6.7cm, minimum width=7.2cm, label={[above, very thick, font = \large] 
\textbf{ABC}}](celll) at (3.5,-2.7){} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{cell/.style={rectangle, rounded corners=5mm, fill=green!15, draw,very thick,}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
\node [cell, minimum height =6.7cm, minimum width=7.2cm, 
label={[font = \large\bfseries,rotate=-90,anchor=south]right:ABC}](celll) at (3.5,-2.7){} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The same answer remodeled

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{
        cell/.style={
            rectangle, rounded corners=5mm, fill=green!15, draw,very thick,minimum height =6.7cm, minimum width=7.2cm, },
        every label/.style={
            font=\large\bfseries, rotate=-90, anchor=south}
        }
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
        \node [cell, label=0:zero](){}  ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: understood and answer edited please